Entry back to Poland
Hi I have valid Poland TRC valid till January 2026. I am living in India from last 1.5 years due to my wife has serious illness. Can i enter in Poland before my TRC expires ?

If it's valid until January 2026, why are you concerned that you cannot enter?

Do you still fulfil the conditions on which the TRC was granted?

yes i have still work contract valid
